# AD LDS cannot connect to port 389

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, ldap, ad-lds

I am trying to replicate an AD domain to a server hosting AD Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS).

In the instance setup wizard, I am choosing "A replica of an existing instance". After I enter the FQDN of any domain controller & port 389, it fails immediately with:

> AD LDS cannot connect to port 389 on server.FQDN. Verify that the server name and port are correct, and try again.

[pic of error msg from AD LDS setup wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKGqh.png)

I can successfully telnet to any domain controller on port 389.  I have tried a win2k8r2 server in the domain and a win2012r2 server outside the domain on the same subnet (I added FQDN of DC's to hosts file).  Both exhibit the same error.

Comment: The goal is to have LDAP available to internal and external (internet) requests.  There will be 2 LDS servers in a DMZ and behind a load balancer. 

LDAP requests are currently being serviced by a single domain controller and only internally.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly you are trying to replicate a full Active Directory domain controller to an AD LDS instance. If so, you have to use [ADAM Sync](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2012/11/12/adamsync-101/). The "replica of an existing instance" is only for connecting to another AD LDS instance.